# how to read smart card on java spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, provider, smartcard-reader

I am trying to read smart card. Sun package was used for reading smart card but it is not available in spring boot application.
So I want new libraries for my purpose. Can you help me?
Thanks.

I tried sun package on spring boot application. But it gives this error message:

```
org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Comment: You haven't tried the sun package you tried to run the applicaiton on a non compatible JDK version.

Comment: I used jre because sun package works in jre. jdk has not that package.

Comment: You didn't use the proper JRE (also the JDK is the JRE with some additional stuff) that is still an older version then the version you need for Spring Boot. However newer JDKs might not have that part of the classes (or the specific JDK in use).